# Upload images/videos to server using Servlet and Android Studio

Tags: android, servlets

I am trying to upload Images/Videos which are taken through Device camera to server at a specific folder which can be retrieved later in a dashboard.

I have gone through numerous posts and tutorials and all of them are basically using a JSP to choose a file and then upload it or they are using PHP as a server side code to upload it.

I have my whole backend developed in JAVA SERVLET and I need to include this upload/download functionality.

Basically what I want is to make a POST request using Retrofit or Volley to make a server request and file should be uploaded. (It's like when we use POSTMAN to fire an api call and choose an image as binary file to upload).

Links which I have tried :

[Link 1](https://www.journaldev.com/2122/servlet-3-file-upload-multipartconfig-part) , [Link 2](https://www.journaldev.com/1964/servlet-upload-file-download-example#servlet-upload-file), [Link 3](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/07/ile-upload-example-in-servlet-and-jsp-java-web-tutorial-example.html) and a lot more. All of them include JSP or something to choose file, I need to pass the media(image/video) as a parameter to the POST request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally managed to achieve it. I had to post an image/video as well as a JSON corresponding to that media.

My solution is as follows :

```
@WebServlet("/ImageUploadServlet")
@MultipartConfig
public class ImageUploadServlet extends HttpServlet {
..............
.............

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    long req_received_time=System.currentTimeMillis();
    String to_be_saved_location="";
    System.out.println("JSON received is : "+request.getParameter("input_json"));    
    JSONObject req = null;
    try {
        req = readPOST(request.getParameter("input_json"));
        to_be_saved_location = "your_location";
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        SqlUtil.incident_reporting(xxx);// function to enter data in sql
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    InputStream in = request.getPart("image").getInputStream();//change it to video(it's just a parameter name)
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/Users/driftking9987/Documents/Stuffs/"+to_be_saved_location+".jpg");//Add .mp4 for video
    //OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/var/www/html/media/abc.mp4");
    copy(in, out); //The function is below
    out.flush();
    out.close();

}

public static long copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

    long count = 0L;
    int n = 0;

    while (-1 != (n = input.read(buffer))) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, n);
        count += n;
    }
    return count;
}
```

While saving it on the server, I gave the tomcat user the permission to write in the `media` folder.

Below is the POSTMAN screenshot.

[image]